# syntax highlight template literal string in codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am unable to highlight template literal string in codemirror. It is working perfect for everything except it is unable to highlight template literal syntax.

Example: it will not highlight this string:

```
var p = `<div>sometext</div>`
```

My initilization code is as like below.

```
JSeditor = CodeMirror(document.getElementsByClassName("control-code")[0], {
        value: "function myScript(){return 100;}\n",
        tabMode: "indent",
        mode: "text/javascript",
        keyMap: "sublime",
        theme: "monokai",
        tabSize: 2,
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers", "CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],
        styleActiveLine: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        autoCloseTags: true,
        foldGutter: true,
        dragDrop: true,
        lint: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
        showInvisibles: true,
        maxInvisibles: 16 // optional
    });
```

I am also using js-lint for validation. It is giving me error for template literal string:

```
"template literal syntax is only available in es6 (us esversion 6)"
```

Comment: Template string support was added in [this commit back in 2013](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/commit/d85b8c4c980fc54a2e52950622feb939c0013e8f#diff-9812850bb71d31e8dd60b476abb2bae8), when they were still called "quasi literals". Are you using an ancient CodeMirror version? Your example code is highlighted just fine in the [demo on the CodeMirror homepage](http://codemirror.net/). In the default theme, it becomes orange rather than the red of normal string literals. Could you create a minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: yes. it is working without theme: "monokai", highlighting with red color. But I want to use monakai theme. How can I highlight with monakai theme?

Comment: You should probably submit a patch to that theme to add this support.